# Problem using Xonar Essence STX on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm having trouble getting input or output from my firend's Xonar Essence STX on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm setting up a studio system for him, and didn't expect this much trouble.

I installed QJack and attempted some connections from the sound card to QTractor. (The audio editing software I installed for him.)

I'm pretty new to all of this, and have been unable to discern whether or not the connections on QJack will affect whether or not I can see noise going in or out of the system on the Sound settings panel.

On the Sound settings panel, I see several inputs that are obviously related to the sound card. I double checked that the sound card had the extra power required from the PSU, although I assume I would not be seeing inputs/outputs in the Sound panel if it was not getting that power.

I am inputting from an analog sound table with a 6.3MM cable. I confirmed that I am indeed registering the instruments connected to the sound table by removing the 6.33MM from the sound card and inserting it into an external speaker system. I have a headphone set attached to the sound card's 6.33MM output.

I have used the "Test Sound" button in the Sound settings panel with the headphones connected on every listed output. I have also attempted to see if there is any audio input by pressing keys on one of the instruments on every listed input in the Sound panel. I neither hear nor see anything.

I have done the above with every possible combination of connections in QJack, and also with the QJack server stopped.

Ubuntu seems to have the drivers for the sound card, but I'm wondering if that is the problem also.

How can I diagnose the issue, whether it be with QJack, or the drivers Ubuntu is using for the sound card?

Comment: AFAIK PulseAudio does not support the Xonar cards correctly. To configure the I/Os, try running `alsamixer` and selecting the card directly.

Comment: I'll give this a try later today and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have that exact card and I can't say I have had any issues on any version of Ubuntu. I don't use this QJack program you speak of though. I will have a think and get back to you later after I've had a chance to look at my home settings.